# Visual Studio 2019 Icon Extension and Spellchecker Error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-project

I want to migrate from VSCode to Visual Studio 2019 but I have three questions:

Is there a way to "ignore all" or "add all to dictionary" in VS as there is VSCode?

Is there a plugin - extension that modifies the icons as I have done in VSCode?:   I want to be able to see HTML with orange icon CSS with 3 etc.

Is there a plugin - extension that can let you work at 2-3 projects at the same time like there is in VSCode?

See screenshots.

https://i.postimg.cc/nLrR8DfQ/Code-Yn-GMMwu-Wb-V.png

https://i.postimg.cc/Qd04nqw3/devenv-hfkr-Rtfn5-G.png

Comment: Is this feature in vs-code itself, or is it reflected by the vs code extension? If it is the extension, you could share with us.

Comment: what feature exactly ? guide me and I will help you :)

Comment: Are these functions vs code itself or vs-code extension?

Comment: 1) ignore all its vscode function
2) extension that modifies the icons (material icon)
3) add multiple projects (project manager extension)